# PhpStorm - Autocomplete JS modules from Resource Root

Tags: vue.js, module, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm as IDE and I want to import my JS modules from my Resource Root with `@` prefix. I've already marked `src` directory as 'Resource Root' and I've also checked the "Use path relative to the project" in **File/Settings/Code Style/Javascript/Imports**.

In fact, the modules are imported correctly if I do for example: `@/components/HelloWorld.vue`, but I noticed that in this way I lost the autocompletion and the possibility to navigate through the files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>MOUSE CLICK</kbd>.

So is there a way to resolve this and to enable the autocomplete of path?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking a folder as **Resource root** tells the IDE to resolve paths relative to this folder, but doesn't allow specifying any prefixes/aliases. 
If your are using *Vue cli 3*, the right way to get your paths resolved is specifying `node_modules\@vue\cli-service\webpack.config.js` as **webpack configuration file** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, in this way it's working :D. I want to add only one more thing about your solution, in my case I also had need to invalidate the cache and restart PHPStorm